# js array to json converting, result is blank page

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have a problem with my js array to json converter, I got no result, but I don't know what is the problem.

My source (in external file):

```
var data = new Array(); data[0] = new Array('Joe','1973-12-11','Male'); data[1] = new Array('Harris','1957-12-11','Male'); data[2] = new Array('Sarah','1974-03-22','Female');
```

My code:

```
  <html>
    <head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="json2.js">
    </script>
    <script src="source.php" type="text/javascript" 

    language="javascript"></script>


    </head>
    <body>


    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    <!--

    $(document).ready(function () {


    var json = data;

            var tr;
            for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    console.log(json[i])

                tr = $('<tr/>');
                tr.append("<td>" + json[i][0] + "</td>");
                    tr.append("<td>" + json[i][1] + "</td>");
                    tr.append("<td>" + json[i][2] + "</td>");
                $('table').append(tr);
            }
        });


    </script>
    <table>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I got a blank page for result, I don't know why.

Comment: where is your jquery file.... please include jquery

Comment: I have no jquery file. I have a simple js source what I added at the beginning of this page.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: This has nothing to do with php nor json. You are misunderstanding what json is, it is the string notation of a javascript object. And no jQuery => no `$`, no `.append()`, etc.

Comment: you are using `$(document).ready` and `$('table').append` which are jQuery functions, not vanilla JavaScript. Without jQuery on the page, these two calls will fail. Check your console.

Answer (score 1):

Actually all your problem is caused by this line:

```
tr = $('<tr/>');
```

Here a selector is expected a `tag name`, a `class` or an `id` while you are specifying a string conatining HTML which is wrong, change it like this:

```
tr = $('tr');
```

That's why you whould get:

> SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

Also move the table outside your script tag: in the body:

```
 </script>
    <table>
    </table>
 </body>
```

Comment: No, this is not problem. I tried to change, but not solved the problem.

Comment: @Terminus Also note that you should move `<table>
        </table>` outside your script tag.

Comment: @chkdsk I already do this, now there is no error in the javascript console, just the blank white page

Comment: I think the problem is related to your data, try `console.log(json[i])` in every iteration and see what it gives.

Comment: @chkdsk I modified my code part to:  tr.append("<td>" + console.log(json[i][0]) + "</td>");
            tr.append("<td>" + console.log(json[i][1]) + "</td>");
            tr.append("<td>" + console.log(json[i][2]) + "</td>");    it not helps, still blank page

Comment: **No** not inside `tr.append()` just the next line after `for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) { console.log(json[i]) ...`

Comment: @chkdsk: I updated my code, please view it. There is still blank white page, and no errors in javascript console.

Comment: If you aren't getting any data result in the console using `console.log(json[i])` it means that you are getting an empty data result, I think you should put data in the same file.

Comment: but if I open my source.php in browser, I got the result what I added at the beginning at this site. so it is not empty.

Comment: I think you should put data in the same file.

Comment: I added the source to my code, but the result is the same

Comment: One additional info: In the firefox console I see at logs the content of the source: Array [ "Joe", "1973-12-11", "Male" ] load.php:30:0
Array [ "Harris", "1957-12-11", "Male" ] load.php:30:0
Array [ "Sarah", "1974-03-22", "Female" ] load.php:30:0       At load.php row 30. there is console.log(json[i])

Comment: Have you tried your code with `tr = $('tr');`?

Comment: Yes, I tried. If I change to your code, then the result not visible. With <tr/> the result visible

Answer (score 0):

If you have not included jQuery, include it like this:

`<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>`

No need for stringify. Just assign `data` to your `json` variable, or iterate over `data` directly:

```
var json = data;
```

Your `source.php` file should look like something this:

```
<?php
header("content-type: application/x-javascript");
echo"var data = new Array(); data[0] = new Array('Joe','1973-12-11','Male'); data[1] = new Array('Harris','1957-12-11','Male'); data[2] = new Array('Sarah','1974-03-22','Female');
";
```

And create table element, or place it in your html first:

```
<table></table>
```

Also change indexes from 1,2,3 to 0,1,2:

```
var tr;
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    tr = $('<tr/>');
    tr.append("<td>" + json[i][0] + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + json[i][1] + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + json[i][2] + "</td>");
    $('table').append(tr);
}
```

Output:

```
Joe 1973-12-11  Male
Harris  1957-12-11  Male
Sarah   1974-03-22  Female
```

Comment: still blank page the result

Comment: Add empty `table` element to html, otherwise `$('table')` will not match anything

Comment: I modified, but still blank white page :(

Comment: Check your console. Your code as-is won't work because you are using jQuery functions without including jQuery on the page. You should have a JS error saying that `$` is an unknown function.

Comment: I updated my code, I included the jquery also, plus the changes what you said, but the result is the same, blank white page for me

Comment: why `source.php` is php file instead of js? When I place `data` directly before your function, it works OK, I don't know where your `data` array is supposed to be taken from.

Comment: @Terminus — Look at your browser's JavaScript console. You have a very obvious error that it will highlight. Also make use of http://validator.w3.org/nu/ as you have errors that can potentially break your code.

Comment: I got this message at javascript console: SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

Comment: Remove `</table>` from inside your script! You should put it directly after `<table>`! Like this: `<table></table>`

Comment: I have source.php because it is a js array which updated daily.

Comment: OK, make sure your PHP file looks like in my edited answer.

Comment: thanks the answers for everbody. n-dru : my source is not the same what you wrote in your source. just what I added to the beginning of this site. Or I must add the extra contents to the source?

Comment: my source is beginning with: var data

Comment: @n-dru : I could try, but I don't know. If I simply generate a html table with my js array then it works without errors.

Comment: my plan is convert to json and add to mysql later

Comment: I updated all my code, but the result is the same, blank white page.

Comment: I think until console.log(json[i]) there is no problem, because at the firefox console I see the element of the array, but if I load my php at browser, the result is a blank page.

Comment: I solved the problem, it works successfull. I edited the code. Thanks guys!